# how to enable xcode precompiled source files

Tags: ios, xcode

guys,
I was using xcode to start a project which links to a static lib project.(I add the project as the child of the target project and add .a to the target)
Every time, I run the target, it has to recompile all the files from the lib project whether or not the source files in the static lib project has changed.
How to stop it from recompile the static lib project? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe you should start by accepting some of the answers already answered to your questions... It could help getting answers in this one...

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a straight answer to your question but i run through this [blog](http://www.blog.montgomerie.net/easy-xcode-static-library-subprojects-and-submodules) with a step-by-step instruction to create a `static lib` in XCode. I have tried myself to see if the static lib was rebuilt when i was just editing the target project but it didn't seem to occur.

Few hints to consider:

- Check the scheme you are using when building your target (Parallelize
  Build and Find Implicit Dependencies should be both turn on).
- Make sure you don't clean your lib project.

Answer (score 0):

you can also construct your own framework and use this projects. [I did it using this link](http://db-in.com/blog/2011/05/creating-universal-framework-to-iphone-ios/)